# Does session.Load<T>(new string[0]) hit Raven?

Tags: ravendb

If I call

```
session.Load<MyDocumentClass>(ids);
```

Where `ids` is actually an empty string array, is any call to the database actually made? Or any other resource set / up consumed, like a connection or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ids` is an empty list, it won't query the database.
Note that this isn't a good behavior to rely on, why are you calling this with an empty list?